# How do I get Java's update to stop "reminding" me to install what it's already installed?

Tags: java

The Java updater/installer insists that I need to install an upgrade to version 7.45. It insists on doing this over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over, etc. I've installed it already, weeks ago. How do I get it to stop? To realize that it's already on my upgraded Java on my machine and doesn't need to do it again.

Comment: Maybe I missed it, but what OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has happened to me before, and AFAIK, it's a glitch in Java's updater. Possibly files that were not updated properly during the installation process.
I'd simply uninstall java (all various versions you may have listed in Programs & Features in the control Panel in Vista/7/8, or Add/Remove Programs in XP) and reboot. After this, go to Sun's [Java Uninstallation support page] and run the Uninstaller utility that's linked to at the top. Reboot after it's done its thing. Next, reinstall Java, and hopefully you'll have only the latest, fully updated copy of Java installed on your computer.